# NoReverseMatch Django - Attribute printing elsewhere in file?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-urls

I am getting a 'No reverse match' error in my Django DeleteView template. I have done some research, and this is supposedly caused when an attribute for a url redirect is blank.

The error looks like the following, *however* the success button redirect works as expected, it is only erroring on my 'cancel' option.

[image]

In this case, the url thats generating this error looks like the following:

```
 <a class="mt-3 mb-3 btn btn-secondary" id="cancel-btn" href="{% url 'post-detail' object.id %}">Cancel</a>
```

This would mean that, 'object.id' is blank/null...

*However*, I have added this attribute into a paragraph tag within the same template, and am seeing the correct value print (in this case, 3).

```
{% block content %}
<div>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %} <!--required security token-->
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Delete Event</legend>
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete the post "{{object.id}}"?</p>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-danger m-3" type="submit">Yes, Delete</button>
            <a class="mt-3 mb-3 btn btn-secondary" id="cancel-btn" href="{% url 'post-detail' object.id %}">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

[image]

Perhaps I have incorrectly typed my code, but I can't seem to figure out how the value could possibly get erased and is unable to be referenced for the cancel button href?

My urls.py for reference:

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", EventPostListView.as_view(), name="event-blog-home"),
path("event/<int:pk>/", EventPostDetailView.as_view(), name="post-detail"),
path("event/new/", EventPostCreateView.as_view(), name="post-create"),
path("event/<int:pk>/update/", EventPostUpdateView.as_view(), name="post-update"),
path("event/<int:pk>/delete/", EventPostDeleteView.as_view(), name="post-delete"),
]
```

All the create, list(post-detail) and update views include this and work as expected.

Comment: You use `post.pk` whereas it should (probably) be `object.pk`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @willeM in the comments, I have solved this issue. Within my template file for DeleteView I was using 'post.pk' as opposed to 'object.pk' as a reference to the model instance.